# How to show rigorously that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f(x-y) = - \frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} f(x-y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know for $F(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $F(x,y) = f(x-y)$ very intuitively that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f(x-y) = - \frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} f(x-y)$. However, I've been trying to show it using a change of variables and having limited success. Does this follow from something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map $\mathbb R^{2n}\to\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is defined by $(x,y)\mapsto x-y\mapsto f(x-y)$ for some $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, where $x,y$ are $n$-tuples. Since this a composition of functions it is best to apply the chain rule, which states that $(f\circ g)'=f'\circ g'$ (shortly).

Comment: Let $g(x, y) = x - y$. Then $\frac{\partial}{x_j} f(g(x, y)) = \frac{df}{dg}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j} = \frac{df}{dg} = \frac{df}{dg}\left(-\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}\right).$

Comment: Yes! The point is $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j}=-\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}$.